# How to restrict a column to display value if value exists

Tags: pageblocktable, rendered, conditional, nested

I have a pageblocktable that is inside pageblocksection. The pageblocktable has many columns. I want 1 of the columns to appear only if it exist.

Following is my code...

```
   <apex:pageblocksection title="Order infos" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">           
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.con}" var="p">   
                <apex:column colspan="7"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">#</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!p.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!p.Name}"/>
              </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column>
                     <apex:facet name="header">Material Name</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.gew_material_name__c}"/>
                 </apex:column....
```

I dont wan't the **below** nested table **Shipment Info** for the **Order infos** if there are no shipments info available.

```
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Info"  collapsible="true" columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.opp}" var="q">
                          <apex:column > 
                                 <apex:facet name="header">Shipment Lines</apex:facet>
                                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!q.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!q.Name}"/>          
                           </apex:outputLink>
                          </apex:column> gew_quantity_shipped__c
```

For now a blank pagetable with all the column header shows like the below image. Ineed to show shipment info only if there are values, records.
[image: No NULL Shipments!!]
Is this possible through rendered or javascript?

Comment: Try adding rendered = {!NOT(ISNULL(gp.opp))}. ie  <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Info"  collapsible="true" columns="1" rendered = {!NOT(ISNULL(gp.opp))}>

Comment: Thnx rao for replying the quick reply. Your answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

rendered attribute should help you hide the page block section.

Try adding

> `rendered = {!NOT(ISNULL(gp.opp))}`

. ie

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Info" collapsible="true" columns="1" rendered = {!NOT(ISNULL(gp.opp))}>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact used the **rendered** attribute to do this.  For the :

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Order infos" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
```

you need to put logic in the controller to check the columns of each row and you can then use that variable on the columns.

The next one is easy:

```
 <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Info"  collapsible="true" columns="1" rendered="{!gp.opp.size > 0>
```

Better yet, you can have a getter inside your controller to keep the VF page more polished.

```
 <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Info"  collapsible="true" columns="1" rendered="{!hasShipments}">

public boolean hasShipments()
{
  return !gp.opp.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Thnx @dphil I got the idea after you posted your answer. rao's answer in comment did the trick. I tried your suggestions, I got this error "
The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'
Error is in expression". I should have mentioned that it was retruning NULL. Thnx!